# Unit square in a 2-sided square

Tags: geometry

Let ABCD be a square, |AB|=2. Let EFGH be a unit square included in ABCD (every point of EFGH is inside ABCD). If O is the center of ABCD, is it possible for O to stay outside EFGH?

Comment: Am I missing something? Is that arrangement even possible? How can  EFGH be touching every point in ABCD when ABCD has sides length 2 and EFGH has sides length 1?

Comment: @Loocid OP means every point of EFGH is _inside_ ABCD.

Comment: @Arpan I see, that makes more sense, thanks.

Comment: It is possible for $O$ to stay on a side or vertex of $EFGH$, but I don't think it can be entirely outside $EFGH$.

Answer (score 1):

At most it can stay on edge or corner of red square EFGH as shown in accompanying diagram. For such doubts I suggest a practical approach:

Cut out the square figures from card board or paper and shift the positions to extreme positions. After all, that is what we do mentally while answering your question. [image]

Comment: Unfortunately, playing with paper and scissors will not provide any proof :(

Comment: But it provides you the most necessary impetus that sustains you in your proof. As it is often said about intuition:  *" Experience comes first, explanation follows"*